# SES email receiving not forwarding addresses on some subdomains

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, amazon-ses

I have a verified domain in SES, for which I want to receive e-mail for "pseudo" addresses, which instead of being delivered to actual mailboxes are sent to a SNS topic connected to a Lambda function that processes the messages.
This works for most addresses, however for one particular subdomain, let's say info@foobar.mydomain.com, the e-mail messages just bounce as undeliverable. They do not reach my SNS topic. But on all other subdomains such as info@somethingelse.mydomain.com, it works just fine.

The only thing I can think of that makes `foobar.mydomain.com` special is that I have a `TXT` record in Route53 set up for this domain, used for verification purposes with an external tool. This TXT record contains a single, custom, key=value pair.

Could the presence of this TXT record be what is interfering? I suspect so since these addresses worked before adding that TXT record, and all other addresses under my domain also work fine - this is the only exception.

Questions:

- How can I debug why certain messages aren't processed by SES email receiving rule sets? Are there any logs etc to check?
- Does SES check for DNS records before deciding to forward to the configured rule sets when an e-mail message is received for the domain? Would a TXT record for `foobar.mydomain.com` explain why SES would throw away such messages instead of processing them (it sure seems so!)? If so, is there something that must be present in that record to make it work? Note that domains not matching any TXT record *at all* work just fine.